# how to set data from database into a table?

Tags: jquery

i have made  project to set data from database into a table. i have make a code for that but i dont know why that's cant running well.

```js
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"../php/absen/spl_inputselect_data.php",
  success: function(data){
   var list = JSON.parse(data);
   for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++){
    
    var tr = "<tr>";
    
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['no']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['nama']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['tanggal']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['jam_mulai']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['jam_selesai']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['status']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['total']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['bagian']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['cost']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['tugas']+"</td>";
    tr = "</tr>";
    $("#check_data tbody").append(tr);
   }
   return false;
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(data,typeof data) ;` just after function(data) { so we can see what's really in your data ? At first you have to be sure your data returned by php are really json readable

Comment: where i must place that?

Comment: `success: function(data){ console.log(data,typeof data) ;` and take a look at your console, then tell us what's in it

Comment: ahahhahaha... very simple wrong and i dont know it T_T
i just typo.  need more + before = at the last `tr+="</tr>";

Comment: just miss one word and the whole code cant be run t_T

Comment: @PierreGranger btw Piere from my code above. can i add thead?

Comment: Common js pr php mistake. Just next time try to tell in your question what is the error you get (here you should have seen that your HTML code was only rendering </tr> in source code)

Comment: Well you can add thead directly in HTML, like you probably did for tbody, you don't need to do it after your post ? Of if you want it to appears only after post you sould probably write your thead, hide it in css (display:none) and just show it after post `jQuery('#check_data thead').show() ;`

Comment: i try to use that but the Thead place and the Tbody place  not in one line T_T

Comment: @PierreGranger okay pierre im sorry

Comment: Then you need to add your html to your question